# 3 digit number less than 2 digit number when using order by

Tags: xml, xquery

As I mentioned in title, I have like some test and I am supposed to sort number of points descending and that's when it happens, it shows that 3 digit number is less than 2 digit number for example (80,70,50,20,100)
"brojBodova" is number of points btw

let $doc := doc("SemaKolokvijum.xml")

for $a in $doc//kolokvijum/polaganje

order by $a/../@redniBroj  , $a/brojBodova descending

return concat("(" , $a/../@redniBroj , ") " , $a//indeks , " " ,"(" , $a/brojBodova , ") " )

Comment: Can you check that the "numbers" from your sheet are actually being read in as numbers? This usually happens when the numbers are read in as strings.

Comment: @MelissaGuo How do I actually check that ?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-instance-of

Comment: @wst It says that its false, can you help me with that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @MelissaGuo, your integers are strings, so they are sorted quasi-alphabetically instead of numerically.

Assuming `brojBodova` is the number, you would cast it as an integer like this:

```
order by $a/../@redniBroj, $a/xs:integer(brojBodova) descending
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
for $a in $doc//kolokvijum/polaganje/brojBodova
order by  $a/../../@redniBroj, number($a) descending
```